# WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 JMS MessageStore/MessateProcessor fail to handle JSON correctly

Tags: xml, json, wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 with ActiveMQ. I am trying to implement a simple store and forward configuration as per [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores) wso2 documentation.

Here is the proxy I am using to Store in JMS and Forward :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testJMSStorenFwd"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="target.endpoint" value="JMSRcvEndPoint" format="soap11"/>
         <store messageStore="FMSReadings"/>
         <!--send>
            <endpoint key="JMSRcvEndPoint" format="soap11"/>
         </send-->
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Here is the endpoint to which the Message should ultimately be forwarded :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JMSRcvEndPoint">
   <address uri="http://kk1:8282/services/testJMSRcvProxy" format="soap11"/>
</endpoint>
```

Here is the proxy which receives the forwarded message ( it just logs the received message for this test):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testJMSRcvProxy"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
        <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
        <log level="full"/>
        <drop/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <drop/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Here is my messagestore :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageStore xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
              class="org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore"
              name="FMSReadings">
   <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

Here is my MessageProcessor :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
                  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor"
                  name="fwdTotestJMSRcvProxy"
                  messageStore="FMSReadings">
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

I am using a simple curl command with very basic JSON to test this setup like below :

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"mail":"faisal.shaik@youtility.in"}' http://kk1:8282/services/testJMSStorenFwd
```

When I run this the message gets stored and forwarded by the setup ( I can verify from ActiveMQ web UI that a message was enqueued and dequeued) but I get below error in ESB logs :

```
[2013-08-27 14:24:44,052]  INFO -  To: /services/testJMSStorenFwd, MessageID: urn:uuid:bb553e52-ee61-4d15-8c1f-19be1356c8e0, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><mail>faisal.shaik@youtility.in</mail></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2013-08-27 14:24:44,085] ERROR -  Error building message {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to convert JSON to XML payload. Expected a ',' or '}' at character 50 of { "xmlPayload" : <mail>faisal.shaik@youtility.in</mail>}
    at org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder.processDocument(JSONBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
```

If you notice in the testJMSStorenFwd proxy above I've a commented out send section. If I uncomment that and comment out the

```
<property name="target.endpoint" value="JMSRcvEndPoint" format="soap11"/>
         <store messageStore="FMSReadings"/>
```

section, I get the json properly converted to xml and following output in the logs :

```
[2013-08-27 14:53:27,333]  INFO -  To: /services/testJMSStorenFwd, MessageID: urn:uuid:e482aba1-98a9-4181-9c8e-c5110dcefd09, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><mail>faisal.shaik@youtility.in</mail></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
[2013-08-27 14:53:27,346]  INFO -  To: /services/testJMSRcvProxy, MessageID: urn:uuid:e6da7131-60ec-4c92-b204-e3843f7e6e91, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><mail>faisal.shaik@youtility.in</mail></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

As you can see from above, the same input given to messagestore & messageprocessor mechanism using same settings results in JSON to XML conversion errors.

Is this a bug in the wso2 esb MessageStore &/or MessageProcessor or am I doing something wrong? 
Is there a way to get rid of the errors I am getting while using this JMS store & forward without resorting to the script mediator?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to implement REST to SOAP scenario. http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-RESTClientandSOAPService

Try removing the `messageType` property from your proxy.

Comment: Yes I have tried it by removing the messageType property. It still gives the exact same error.

Did you read the entire question? The error is only while using the JMS Messagestore and Messageprocessor. If I use a simple send mediator and pass through to the receiver proxy ( same in both cases) I do not get the error. This leads me to believe there is a difference in the way the Messagestore & Messageprocessor do JSON to XML conversion than other mediators. Hence the question if there is a bug therein or should I be handling this differently?